# jqgrid disable default client side sorting and handle it manually

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

i am using jqgrid with **datatype:'local'**, 
i manually handled sorting and while on sorting i fetch the data from server and bind using **addRowData** , 
but **before my sorting event** the default client side sorting of jqgrid occurs.

Answer (score 0):

before fetching the sorted **clear the records** in the grid by using  `$('#gridelementid').jqGrid('clearGridData');`